# Laravel Snappy - footer not inheriting styles

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the following [library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) to generate PDFs from my views.

Now I am trying to do a custom footer so I created a footer view with the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <address>
            //Some Address
        </address>
    </div>
</footer>
```

As per the docs I set the DOCTYPE.  Now my main view is where I load the css files etc.  In my Controller I do the following

```
$footer = \View::make('projects.clients.footer')->render();

$pdf = \PDF::loadView('projects.clients.template', compact('project'))->setOption('footer-html', $footer);
return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

So as far as I can tell I am doing everything correctly.  Now my PDF displays the footer, but it has none of my own styling applied to it.  If I try to load some CSS files within the footer template, the footer does not display.

How can I make sure the footer has the appropiate styles applied to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to load your css like that:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```